# Do I need to get out of International Zone at Charles de Gaulle airport when changing terminals from 1 to 2e?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, cdg, mongolian-citizens

Do I need to get out of International Zone at Charles de Gaulle airport when changing terminals from 1 to 2e?

I'm flying ULN-Beijing-Paris-Manchester. ULN-Paris is Air China then Paris-MCR is Flybe. I have 3.40 hours between the connecting flight at Charles De Gaulle airport. my problem is that Air China won't check my baggage to my final destination. I have to pick it up then re-check again. If I don't have to leave the international zone of the airport, then I won't need a transit visa. Do I have to leave the international zone and go through passport control to collect my bag and re-check it in again to board Flybe to Manchester? Also is 3:40 hours enough to do all of this when solo traveling with a 3-year-old child? If I decide to travel baggage free and with carry-on only, I don't need to leave transit zone to change terminals?

Than you very much for any advice!

Comment: Are you sure you have the right tickets? There doesn't seem to be any airport with abbreviation MCR close to Manchester -- gcmap.com guesses it's somewhere in Guatemala but calls that "unreliable".

Comment: yeah it's manchester, UK. sorry for the abbrev.

Comment: @HenningMakholm MCR=Manchester City region

Answer (score 1):

To pick up luggage, you **always** have to clear immigration, so you will need a visa.

Even if you only have hand luggage, with separate tickets check-in staff will usually treat Paris as the final destination and deny you boarding without a visa.

So what you need is a short-stay (type C) Schengen visa from the French embassy. If the application form asks for the purpose of the trip, select "transit"

Answer (score 0):

Beijing and Manchester are both international destinations (i.e. outside the Schengen area). [CDG has international airside transfers between all terminals](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/inter-terminal-shuttles). If you have no carry-on, then from terminal 2E, walk or take a shuttle to terminal 2C, then take a shuttle to terminal 1. You won't need to clear immigration in Paris.

If you have luggage that isn't checked through, then as far as I know you'll need to pick it up at the same place as everyone else, and that's after immigration. So in that case you will need to spend more time in a queue, and you will need a transit visa if your citizenship and visa status requires it.

If everything goes well, 3:40 hours is enough. Say 1 hour to clear immigration, ½ hour to reach the other terminal, you have 2 hours to check in for the next flight. With a small child, it may be a bit tight as it doesn't allow much slack for accidents or for resting. The problem is if your incoming flight is late. I strongly recommend to either get the Paris–Manchester flight on the same ticket or to allow a lot more time in Paris.